# Can I make my own mold remover gel (bleach based)?

Tags: mold

I just started using an interesting product to clean all the moldy caulk around the house... an [anti-mold gel](https://www.amazon.com/mold-remover-gel/s?k=mold+remover+gel). Highly effective, but a bit pricy.

It's actually just bleach gel really. You can tell by the smell right away.

I was wondering if I can mix my own? I already know bleach and alcohol is chloroform, so I can't just put some in all the extra hand-sanitizer I got. How would I create the gel for the bleach to go in?

Comment: Why not just use a diluted bleach solution and a rag to apply it?

Comment: Surely there exist ordinary household cleaners besides this pricey stuff, where the ordinary household cleaner is thickened bleach. There you go: https://www.walmart.com/ip/Clorox-Zero-Splash-Bleach-Gel-24-oz/20606802

Comment: The gel that holds the bleach in place, so it works much better. I can splash undiluted consumer bleach on the wall tiles, and it isn't that effective, but this stuff stays on overnight and then solidifies, and completely clears up mold in one application.

Then there's the fact that I just don't want bleach all over the place.

Comment: @Nelson I'm cheap (because I need to save all my money to buy quality tools), and This is why I use bleach. You avoid splashing by applying the bleach to a rag or sponge, then rub the walls. You are already putting bleach on walls with the gel. And I suggested diluted bleach, not undiluted. And the bleach is already what is doing the job in the gel product. I don't write this as an answer because it's not an answer to your question on how to make the gel. I don't have an answer for that.

Comment: Mixing chemicals can be nasty, with dangerous gasses released.  Will alcohol and bleach react dangerously? This question may be better suited to Chemistry.SE. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Or simply use a chip brush or something to brush the solution onto the caulk.

Comment: @Nelson "splash undiluted consumer bleach on the wall tiles" - thin bleach or thick (toilet cleaning bleach)?  The latter is cheap, thick (though maybe not quite as thick as your drying gel), and strong.  It also isn't very splashy

Comment: Good call, @ChrisH. Toilet bowl cleaner will, most likely, do the job for significantly less money! The OPs product is probably nothing more than relabeled toilet bowl cleaner, anyway. Maybe they make it a tad thicker...

Comment: @FreeMan and an old toothbrush to scrub. The job is practically free by that point. This reminds me, my shower needs the same treatment

Comment: @FreeMan Oh! That's actually a good point. I need to try it out. The stuff I'm using is pretty pricy by comparison. I can get at least 4x the amount for the same price.